# notificación local no muestra el App Icon Swift iOS15

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, imageicon

Esto es Lo que estoy obteniendo, pero como tal la app si le aparece el Icono que fijé:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo esto en el info.plist

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo agregado el App Icon:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta configuración en el proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien sabe se lo agradezco, para estas notificaciones estoy utilizando **UNUserNotificationCenter**.Se que debe hacer algo bobo :(

Comment: Dentro del `asset` del `AppIcon` está **"iPhone Notifications"**, debe estar vacío. De preferencia debes llenar todos los espacios con los iconos.

Comment: @Bicho, todos están asignados, en especial ese, ya agregue una imagen de ello.

Comment: @Bicho por ejemplo pasa lo mismo con el Icon de la app como tal, para que me aparezca tengo que reiniciar mi dispositivo, porque conectado a Xcode no se muestra. En algunos foros dicen que es un Bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución fue actualizar a las version IOS 15.0.2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Eso quiere decir que en la versión 15.0 no funciona? Que pasa si tú app la ejecutan en versiones menores?

Comment: @Bicho, no en esas versiones debajo de ella parece que no y en muchos foros comentaban este Bug, el cual esta ultima version comentan que arreglaron ese bug y así fue. Si ejecutan versiones inferiores podría pasar que no se muestre el logo, aunque es una teoría porque supongo que si esta subida en la AppStore no debería pasar eso, pero vi en un foro que hay gente que le a pasado con algunas apps como en este link:     https://www.reddit.com/r/ios/comments/pvqhvl/missing_app_icons_in_spotlightnotifications/